# RStudio unresponsive when saving a new script or a knitr pdf

Tags: save, windows-8.1, rstudio, knitr

I am constently running into a really annoying problem.

I work under windows 8.1, 64bits, and Rstudio Version 0.99.441. on R3.2.0

I can't save a new script, open an old one, or a pdf output of knitr, because it freezes. To be precise: either the browser to access my files does not appear, or it appears but freezes while i write the name of the script, or when i click on "save" button.

in fact it happens every time i want to access my files.

When i open the task manager, it also freezes, and so on, until i shut down the computer...

I have uninstalled and re-installed r and rstudio many times, without changes (might even have gotten worse, as on older versions, it would sometimes work without freezing)

every time i open rstudio, windows opens a window saying that it does know the editor, so i have to authorise rstudio to launch.

Everything works well on R gui 3.2.0 though...

any help would be great!

thank you for your time